# Такие же(,) лишившиеся всего(,) солдаты

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

> Он растворился в массе таких же, лишившихся всего, солдат.

Возможны ли поставленные запятые?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны как уточнение - каких именно **таких же**, без запятых тоже не будет ошибкой, потому что указательные местоимения часто не требуют уточнения, даже с одной запятой не будет ошибкой, потому что уточняющие определения синонимичны однородным определениям:

*Он растворился в массе таких же, лишившихся всего солдат.*